# Get button clicked with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to know how to detect if a button with a certain id is clicked on a webpage with my chrome extension.
With my code I have an error saying that my element is undefined.
Here is my manifest :

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "app",
"description": "my app",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Changer le background"
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
]
```

}

And my popup.js file :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
getCurrentTabUrl((url) => {
    document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var script = "console.log('clicked');";
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: script});
    });
});
```

});

Comment: You have to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) injected on the webpage.

Comment: can you show me an example ? I'm reading the google dev documentation and I don't understand how it solves my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your popup.js will not load until the user himself will click on the extension's icon... i think you should change your approach and use a content-script like this:

```js
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
});
```

you'll need to update your manifest.json for using a content script, something like that:

```js
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["the url of a page for the script", "the url of another page"],
    "js": ["your_script.js"]
   }
   ],
```