# Ajax post request from google chrome extension to Laravel 5.5 app

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, google-chrome-extension, csrf

I'm new to web dev. 
I'm developing a laravel app with a google chrome extension to send a post request to laravel app using jquery ajax.

When I comment this line `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` in App\Http\Kernel.php

My form get posted and I hit Status Code: 200.

But if I uncomment that line I get Status Code: 419.

Here is my popup.html code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class=" form-group content">
        <p>
            <h1 class="title"></h1>
        </p>
        <div>
            <form id="form" method="POST" action="https://app.test/">
<input type="url" name="url" id="input" class=" form-control form-group input" autocomplete="off">


                <div class="formbtn">
                    <button id="button" class="btn" type="submit">Publish </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my popup.js code:

```
 taburl = "";
chrome.tabs.query(
{
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, 
function(tabs) {
    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var  link = tab.url;
    $("#input").val(link);
    var str = tab.title;
    var res = str.substring(0,20);
    $('.title').html(res+ '...');

    taburl = link;
}
);


$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
$("#button").on("click", ajaxCall);

});

$("#input").val(taburl);

function ajaxCall(element) {
$.ajax({
        url : "https://app.test/",
        data : {
            "_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "url" : taburl,
            },
        method : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("sent url = " + taburl);
        }
});
}



 Here is the screenshot of the network tab:
```

[Here is screenshot of the response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUhoq.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your api.php route instead.  for security you can use laravel passport or something similar to create a token to authenticate your users or access token.

Hope this help!

Answer (score -2):

pretty much the same as here:
[Get button clicked with chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246397/get-button-clicked-with-chrome-extension/48251479#48251479)

you should use a content-script for that, your popup "sleeps" until the user opens it.

Comment: I'm using content_scripts. the question is about the Ajax request how to have csrf token include in the form. so that laravel can validated.

Comment: i meant that your code, starting from

$(document).ready(function() {

should be on a content-script

Comment: maybe adding headers to $.ajax itself will help, there might be a problem because they're on a different scope

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't help.